# uninitialized constant UserController/undefined method `user_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

ok, i have users, and i want to have the options to edit their names. my route looks like this

```
namespace :admin do
    resources :users
end
```

my index:

```
   - @users.each do |user|
   %tr
      %td= link_to user.last_name, admin_user_path(user)
      %td= user.first_name
      %td= link_to "Edit", edit_admin_user_path(user), class: "btn"

= paginate @users
```

controller

```
class Admin::UsersController < AdminController
    def edit
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end
```

and the form:

```
= simple_form_for @user do |f|
  %p New first name
  = f.input :first_name
  %p New last name
  = f.input :last_name
  = f.button :submit
```

When i press the 'edit' button on the index page, it gives me 'undefined method `user_path'' error, pointing into first line of the form. i tried to solve it poorly with adding 
    resources :users
and it allowed me to render form, but when i try to save it, it gives me uninitialized 'constant UsersController'. What is going on with this user_path since i'm not using it anywhere? how can i solve this problem, best would be without any extra routes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the form to

`=simple_form_for [:admin, @user] do |f|`